# sharing internet connection

Tags: wireless, internet, android, connection, tablet

Greeting,
I have a portable model. I am intended to use it to share internet connection from ubuntu 13.04 to my android tablet. can anybody help me how can I setup my ubuntu 13.04 as a server in order to share the internet connection to my android tablet?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you need to have two network interfaces in order to share an internet connection. You connect one interface (probably the wired connection) to the internet and on the other (probably the wireless connection) you create a shared network. (I don't know how / if that works over bluetooth.)

Step by step:

1. Plug in the wired internet connection.
2. Click on the network-manager icon and select "edit connections"
3. Create a new connection in the wireless tab

   - choose name and security as you like
   - make sure to select "mode: ad-hoc"
   - in the "IP4 Properties" tab, select "shared connection" from the drop down menu
4. Now click on the network-manager icon again, "create new network" and select the network you just configured
5. Now your Android device should find the new wireless network, connect and you're ready to go.

Comment: Hello, thanks for this post, but my android/samsung cannot see this way created wi-fi. Tried on android to connect to a hidden network but nothing. Any tips out there? Cheers.

Comment: Found reason for my problem (Acer netbook Ubuntu 13.04) here https://github.com/opentechinstitute/commotion-mesh-applet/issues/5

Comment: tomasb, it's an ad-hoc network. That means it'll only connect when two or more devices connect to it. So "connect" to the network on Ubuntu and then enter the network details on your adroid device. Probably under "connect to hidden network" or something similar. Then it should work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on Ad-hoc and switched to full Wireless AP which is even better (more then one device can connect), got it working using the script found here http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ap-hotspot

sudo ap-hotspot start

ap-hotspot
```

Comment: your hardware must support this but it probably will, my acer aspire one netbook does

Comment: dell latitude D830's wi-fi doesn't support it